# How to detect if a sprite is a different color than another at a certain point?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision, skspritenode, color-detection

I'm going to try to get straight to the point. I'd be surprised if anyone knew how to help me on this.

I'll try my best to describe what I need.

I have two rectangles that fall down the screen at a certain rate and then once those two fall off, two new ones begin falling. There is a gap between the two rectangles that you are trying to fit a ball into. The ball will either be red, green, or blue. The two rectangles will be the same color as each other, but can also be red, green, or blue. I need to somehow detect if, when my ball enters the gap, if the color of the ball and the color of the two rectangles are the same. IS THIS POSSIBLE?

Here is the code that randomly picks the colors of the ball and rectangles.

```
 var colorBucket = [UIColor]()

func randomColor() -> UIColor {

    if colorBucket.isEmpty {
        fillBucket()
    }

    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colorBucket.count)))
    let randomColor = colorBucket[randomIndex]
    colorBucket.removeAtIndex(randomIndex)
    return randomColor

}

func fillBucket() {
    colorBucket = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.blueColor()]
}
```

I can't figure this out.

I was thinking that I would need a spritekitnode attached to each rectangle and when the ball collided would check if the two colors are the same. Is there another way? Any help would be appreciated.

[This is what it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdNeG.png)

Comment: Are the rectangles and the ball `SKSpriteNode`(s)?

Comment: @appzYourLife Yes.

Comment: And are they custom classes?

Comment: @appzYourLife  let Wall1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Walls")
and let Ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ball") I don't know what you mean by custom classes. This is what I have

Comment: Look my answer below

Comment: @appzYourLife Do I need to change any of my code? Where do I put the classes? Do I need to modify your answer at all?

Comment: I added a new section to my answer, please take a look.

Comment: @appzYourLife Don't want to annoy you at all. But I can't just set my Wall to a color like red. It can be red, green, or blue because of the randomization in my code above. Depending on what it is, I need to then check if my ball is the same color as my wall ONLY when it reaches the very bottom of the wall. I' m trying my best to make sense.

Comment: Yes please look ad the update section in my answer

Comment: Did you try my code?

Comment: @appzYourLife Yes. It didn't work. I can't just set my wall1.color = to red because its randomly selected every few seconds to be another color.

Comment: And why can't you update the color of the sprite as soon as a new random color is generated?

Comment: @appzYourLife because the colors change in the middle of the game.

Comment: Ok but you can still change the color of your sprites. I really don't see the problem.

Comment: @appzYourLife I don't want to change the color of them. I want to write an if statement that checks if the ball and the walls it goes between are the same color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Of course it is possible!

Given your `Rectangle` class

```
class Rectangle: SKSpriteNode {
    init(color: SKColor) {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "rectangle")
        super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: texture.size())
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

and you `Ball` class

```
class Ball: SKSpriteNode {
    init(color: SKColor) {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "ball")
        super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: texture.size())
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

You can compare two instances just writing

```
let ball = Ball(color:.redColor())
let rectangle = Rectangle(color:.redColor())

print(ball.color == rectangle.color) // true
```

### Update

It looks like you are not using subclassing of SKSpriteNode.

Infact you are using SKSpriteNode directly like this

```
let wall1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Walls")
let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ball")
```

In this case just remember to add a color to these sprites when you create them

```
wall1.color = .redColor()
ball.color =  .redColor()
```

Now you can compare them by color

```
if wall1.color == ball.color {
    print("same color!")
}
```